# Extending a second GameView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, setcontentview

I'm making an application on Android which is to contain 2 games. I've done this but I've come across a problem that the two buttons that are supposed to extend to different `GameViews` are extending to the same `GameViews`. The classes both have different names and I've tried changing some of the content to specifically refer to the BallGameView class however it causes the program not to compile. I've had a look around to see if there's anything on extending to 2 separate `GameViews` in a single application but not came across anything so far.

EDIT: For clarity, the problem is that the buttons that should open different games are opening the same game. The game is compiling but not as I want it to. I'll post the code that's referring to the different games below.

```
public class BallGameActivity extends Activity {

    GameView GV;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ballgame);
        GV = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(GV);
```

To refer to Ball Game.

```
public class BallSplash extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button playBallButton;
Button guideButton;
Intent ballIntent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ball_splash);

    playBallButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBallGame);
    guideButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.guideButton);

    playBallButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    guideButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.startBallGame:
            ballIntent = new Intent(this,BallGameActivity.class);
            startActivity(ballIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.guideButton:
            ballIntent = new Intent(this,Guide.class);
            startActivity(ballIntent);
            break;
    }

}
```

To refer to Sprite Game

```
public class Splash extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button playButton;
    Button instructionButton;
    Intent intent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toPlay);
        instructionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toInstructions);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        instructionButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.toPlay:
                intent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.toInstructions:
                intent = new Intent(this,InstructionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the error for it not to compile?

Comment: A little unclear what your exact issue is but no you can only extend one class. You could, however, pass params to your GameView class to change the layout if that's what you're trying to do. Also, you aren't extending a GameView anywhere here. You are extending Activity and instantiating the class GameView.

Comment: Is it me only how can't understand the problem?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking, may be you need to show more code

Comment: as far as i´m concerned, it is a compilation error, maybe he lacks the ability to get it to work with inheritance

Comment: post activity_ballgame.xml?

Comment: They are opening the correct Activity but you have `GV = new GameView(this)` so that's going to run the same code for each one. What do you expect to be different?  @hegazy irrelevant because the OP calls `setContentView(GV);` directly after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_ballgame);`

Comment: I tried changing GV to a unique name and set the contentView(BallGameView.class) to specifically refer to the different GameView, but it didn't make a difference. I changed it back to the original code I was running. I'm really just looking for a way to refer specifically to that class (BallGameView).

Comment: `BallGameView GV = new BallGameView(this); Why didn't that work? Is the code in `BallGameView` the same as `GameView`? Those are the classes we would need to see instead of how you are calling the activities.

Comment: It does work in that it refers to the correct class (BallGameActivity), but BallGameView isn't active so it just shows a static image of a ball. The code in GameView and BallGameView are totally different. One is a View game and the other is a SurfaceView game.

Comment: Ok, so in what way does doing `BallGameView GV = new BallGameView(this); setContentView(GV);` not work?

Comment: That did fix it! Thank you so much. The ways I was trying to implement it before brought up the right screen but had no interactivity, it now has that interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem exists because you call `setContentView()` twice. You should remove the wrong one.

Comment: That does make it refer to the correct class, however the GameView isn't working, it's just the activity class now which just has a static image on it.

Comment: The last `setContentView()` is the actually overriding the previous one. Can you provide the code of Guide activity?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is to call that class that you want to use as the view

```
BallGameView GV = new BallGameView(this); 
setContentView(GV);
```

in your current code you are instantiating `GameView` but that isn't what you want for this `Activity`. You need to instantiate `BallGameView GV` instead. Since you are using

```
GV = new GameView(this);
setContentView();
```

in both Activities, you are seeing the same thing no matter which Activity you start. So the problem was never with starting an activity or extending anything.

Also, you can remove

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_ballgame);
```

That line will set the Activity to use that layout. But since you are calling `setContentView()` again and using the class which `extends SurfaceView` then it will set the Activity to use that as the layout instead, making the above line useless.